# HighChart not working when called by ajax

Tags: ajax, highcharts

Hi guys i have a page which is working perfectly it contains a highchart. I want to show this page on the existing page through an ajax call. My ajax is working perfectly but the highcharts are not displaying when i make ajax call.

link of my highchart is

```
http://www.rahatcottage.com/AI/J/examples/line-log-axis/index.php
```

And My ajax script goes here

```
var xmlhtt

 function load(str,str1)
    {


      xmlhtt=GetXmlHttpObject();

     if (xmlhtt==null)
     {
       alert ("Your browser does not support Ajax HTTP");
       return;
       }

        var url="examples/line-log-axis/index.php";
         url=url+"?q="+str;
         url=url+"&q1="+str1;

       xmlhtt.onreadystatechange=getOutpt;
      xmlhtt.open("GET",url,true);
      xmlhtt.send(null);
       }

        function getOutpt()
         {

         if                                     (xmlhtt.readyState==3||xmlhtt.readyState==2||xmlhtt.readyState==1|
       |xmlhtt.readyState==0)

{

         document.getElementById("apDiv1").innerHTML="Loading ";

}

     if (xmlhtt.readyState==4)
      {
      document.getElementById("apDiv1").innerHTML=xmlhtt.responseText;
          document.getElementById("apDiv1").focus();
          }
            }

            function GetXmlHttpObject()
               {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
         {
   return new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
       if (window.ActiveXObject)
       {
  return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
         }
       return null;
           }
```

I guess because highgraphs are using Jquery thats y ajax is not running them

Comment: Your script has an error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
http://www.rahatcottage.com/AI/J/examples/line-log-axis/index.php
Line 44

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**
So what you are doing is, that you have a working chart page, and through ajax you wish to load that page into a `div` of another page. I don't think that will be possible, you can just do that, especially if that page has javascripts, what you are doing is just getting the generated html of the working chart page, and pasting it inside the `div`, this won't run the necessary javascripts for the chart generation.

Try using an iframe instead.

HTML

```
<iframe id="frame" />
```

SCRIPT

```
function load(str,str1)
{
     $('#frame').attr('src', "examples/line-log-axis/index.php?q="+str+"&q1="+str1);
}
```

<del>**OLD**
    series: [{
    data: JSON.parse("[" + text + "]")
    }] 

`text = ','`, hence a json parse error. Revisit your json building @ php to correctly spit `text`</del>

Comment: Guys its not an error actually when i transfer the control to this page i send this text parameter with it . its opening perfectly

Comment: OK, i now get your question. Can you not use an iframe?